# Bring multiple background jobs to foreground

Tags: jobs

I’ve got 2 background jobs running, I got their job ids using `jobs` is it possible to bring them both to the foreground using the `fg <jobId>` cmd? I can’t seem to add 2 parameters.

Comment: Regardless if one can do it, why do you want to do it? What is your goal? (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). Usually background jobs can write to the terminal but they cannot read from it. A foreground job can read from the terminal. If you managed to put two jobs in the foreground, they would steal each other's input.

Comment: I was thinking it might be faster if I bring them both to the foreground, that’s was my reasoning, but from what you said it would cause problems. @kamilmaciorowski

Comment: What exactly did you hope to be faster? The jobs? Or your workflow? If you want to do something or be notified immediately after some jobs finish then get familiar with `wait`. It can take multiple arguments, but sole `wait` is also useful. Example: `wait; date; beep`.

Comment: On a practical level, you cannot pull two jobs into the foreground consecutively anyway. After the first job is fg, the shell gives that process exclusive access to stdin. You need to Ctrl-Z (suspend) that job before you can fg any other job.

Comment: @kamilmaciorowski for the exact same process does running it in the background vs foreground offer any speed increase in execution time?

Comment: A job in the background will be suspended [if it tries to use its controlling terminal](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux). If you don't notice when this happens then obviously the job will unnecessarily remain suspended. Aside from this, no, there is no mechanism to prioritize foreground processes. See this: [*What is the priority of background processes in Linux environment?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29695748/10765659)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't make sense because each job writes to it's own console, you couldn't watch 2 consoles at once.

Think of jobs as an array where you can get 1 item at a time, add 1 at a time, or remove 1 at a time.

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/jobs-bg-fg